# How to prepare an APPEND IMAP Command?

Tags: php, sockets, command, append, imap

I trying to create a Draft in GMail programatically with PHP.

I'm using [VivOAuthIMAP](https://github.com/vmuthal/VivOAuthIMAP) library to make an IMAP login with OAuth successfully but the library only support a few commands to fetch data. I want to extend the library to support APPEND command and achieve my purpose: create a Draft.

But I'm very lost with this IMAP stuff and I don't know how to build a valid IMAP APPEND command, I'm always getting "A3 BAD Could not parse command error" or "A3 BAD [CLIENTBUG] Too many arguments for command: APPEND". I'm trying to follow [RFC2060](http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-2060.txt) example:

```
 C: A003 APPEND saved-messages (\Seen) {310}
 C: Date: Mon, 7 Feb 1994 21:52:25 -0800 (PST)
 C: From: Fred Foobar <foobar@Blurdybloop.COM>
 C: Subject: afternoon meeting
 C: To: mooch@owatagu.siam.edu
 C: Message-Id: <B27397-0100000@Blurdybloop.COM>
 C: MIME-Version: 1.0
 C: Content-Type: TEXT/PLAIN; CHARSET=US-ASCII
 C:
 C: Hello Joe, do you think we can meet at 3:30 tomorrow?
 C:
 S: A003 OK APPEND completed
```

I think the problem is that I'm not building the multi-line message properly. For example:

This works:

```
$this->writeCommannd("A" . $this->codeCounter, "APPEND \"$mailbox\" (\Seen) {$size} \"Subject: hello world\"");
```

But these not (if I add spaces IMAP interprets as new arguments and I get too many arguments).

```
// A3 BAD [CLIENTBUG] Too many arguments for command: APPEND
$this->writeCommannd("A" . $this->codeCounter, "APPEND \"$mailbox\" (\Seen) {$size} \"Subject: hello world\" \"To: myemail@email.com\"");

// A3 BAD Could not parse command
$this->writeCommannd("A" . $this->codeCounter, "APPEND \"$mailbox\" (\Seen) {$size} \"Subject: hello world\"\r\n\"To: myemail@email.com\"");
```

Comment: I think you want to be following RFC3501, not RFC2060. It isn't the cause of your problems, but I'm just letting you know that you aren't following the latest standard. (They are both IMAP4rev1, but RFC3501 is the latest)

Answer (score 5):

Two things:

1. You need a CRLF after the size.  The body is not part of the command.
2. You need to wait for the server to tell you to proceed after the size, unless the server supports the LITERAL+ extension.

Sample dialog:

```
C: A01 APPEND INBOX {100}\r\n
S: + go ahead\r\n
C: {message here}
```

With LITERAL+ extension:

```
C: A01 APPEND INBOX {100+}\r\n
C: {message here}
```